# Use of verb when "either" is used in the sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, exam-questions

For the sentence:

> Either the method used by the student or the techniques used by the teacher __________ a re-examination before we move ahead.

Will we use '**need**' or '**needs**' for the blank?

On reading the sentence for the first time, I thought it would be 'need'. But I am not sure if the verb has to comply with the first part or the second part, where 'either' is concerned.

So what should be the answer?